# Play Framework Scala: How to Stream Request Body

Tags: scala, playframework, streaming

I'm building a micro-service using Play Framework 2.3.x using Scala (I'm a beginner in both) but I can't figure out a way to stream my request body.

Here is the problem:

I need an endpoint `/transform` where I can receive a huge TSV file that I will parse and render in another format: simple transformation. The problem is that every single command in my controller is ran "too late". It waits to receive the full file before starting the code.

Example:

```
  def transform = Action.async {
    Future {
      Logger.info("Too late")
      Ok("A response")
    }
  }
```

I want to be able to read line-by-line the request body during its upload and process already the request without having to wait for the file to be received completely.

Any hint would be welcome.

Comment: parse the request body as multipart-form-data. May be it solve your problem.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This answer applies to Play 2.5.x and higher since it uses the Akka streams API that replaced Play's Iteratee-based streaming in that version.

Basically, you can create a body parser that returns a `Source[T]` that you can pass to `Ok.chunked(...)`. One way to do this is to use `Accumulator.source[T]` in the body parser. For example, an action that just returned data sent to it verbatim might look like this:

```
def verbatimBodyParser: BodyParser[Source[ByteString, _]] = BodyParser { _ =>
  // Return the source directly. We need to return
  // an Accumulator[Either[Result, T]], so if we were
  // handling any errors we could map to something like
  // a Left(BadRequest("error")). Since we're not
  // we just wrap the source in a Right(...)
  Accumulator.source[ByteString]
    .map(Right.apply)
}

def stream = Action(verbatimBodyParser) { implicit request =>
  Ok.chunked(request.body)
}
```

If you want to do something like transform a TSV file you can use a `Flow` to transform the source, e.g:

```
val tsvToCsv: BodyParser[Source[ByteString, _]] = BodyParser { req =>

  val transformFlow: Flow[ByteString, ByteString, NotUsed] = Flow[ByteString]
    // Chunk incoming bytes by newlines, truncating them if the lines
    // are longer than 1000 bytes...
    .via(Framing.delimiter(ByteString("\n"), 1000, allowTruncation = true))
    // Replace tabs by commas. This is just a silly example and
    // you could obviously do something more clever here...
    .map(s => ByteString(s.utf8String.split('\t').mkString(",") + "\n"))

  Accumulator.source[ByteString]
    .map(_.via(transformFlow))
    .map(Right.apply)
}

def convert = Action(tsvToCsv) { implicit request =>
  Ok.chunked(request.body).as("text/csv")
}
```

There may be more inspiration in the [Directing the Body Elsewhere](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaBodyParsers#Directing-the-body-elsewhere) section of the Play docs.

Comment: Thanks! I already figured out it is an issue to make the things I want working on Play 2.3.x. But I will probably try this just for the fun on a 2.5.x.