# Play Framework file upload to in memory to S3

Tags: java, scala, amazon-web-services, playframework

I am writing a web server with Play framework 2.6 in Java. I want to upload a file to WebServer through a multipart form and do some validations, then upload the file s3. The default implementation in play saves the file to a temporary file in the file system but I do no want to do that, I want to upload the file straight to AWS S3.

I looked into this [tutorial](https://github.com/wsargent/play-java-fileupload-example), which explains how to save file the permanently in file system instead of using temporary file. To my knowledge I have to make a custom Accumulator or a Sink that saves the incoming ByteString(s) to a byte array? but I cannot find how to do so, can someone point me in the correct direction?

thanks

Comment: Look at [Play documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaBodyParsers#custom-parsing-using-akka-streams) and [Scala answer] (https://stackoverflow.com/a/38480045/2571592). Hope it helps.

Comment: I got working code for S3 uploading, but with temp file, did you solve your problem?

Comment: nop not yet. I am looking for a java solution. Might have to learn how Akka works to write one